# distinguish between two tables in a union

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to echo the results from both of these tables so far this code works fine however I need to  achieve all the results from `user_statement_lost` to echo out in red and all of `user_statement_won` to echo out in green?
Is there a way to distinguish between the both. Thanks everyone.

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `user_statements_lost` WHERE `note` = "CoinFlip" UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `user_statements_won` WHERE `note` = "CoinFlip" ORDER BY `transactionIdentifier` DESC');
$stmt->execute();

$text = "";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['transactionIdentifier'];
    echo ' - ';
    echo $row['timestamp'];
    echo '<br>';
}
return $text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a flag to each query that indicates it is belong to which group as shown below,
I added text to distinguish them but it can be anything ( 0/1 , TRUE/False , etc):

```
SELECT *, "lost" as flag 
FROM `user_statements_lost` 
WHERE `note` = "CoinFlip" 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, "won" as flag 
FROM `user_statements_won` 
WHERE `note` = "CoinFlip" 
ORDER BY `transactionIdentifier` DESC
```